# Is there a way to run Redis server on multiple nodes or multiple cores of a CPU?

Tags: server, redis, single-threaded

I am currently working on running a deep learning model using Redis server, and for its optimisation, I was wondering if there is a way to run Redis server on multiple nodes, since redis is single threaded.

Comment: I guess there's nothing stopping you from running 2 instances of Redis on two different ports and dividing your data some convenient way across the two.

Comment: Have you looked into Redis Cluster - https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at https://oss.redislabs.com/redisai/ - a module for AI/DL stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely run multiple instances of Redis on one node, just use:

```
redis-server --port 6380
```

You can then test with `redis-cli -p 6380`. Avoid running more instances than cores.

You can split your workload by application scopes. Or you can use [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial). It is a common pattern to use one node to run both a master instance and a replica instance of another master.

Be sure to look at [hash tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags) for cases where you need multi-key operations.

Comment: However, i'm looking for a way to run Redis server on a multi-node environment i.e. a cluster. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: That's what you do with Redis Cluster https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial

Comment: I'm unable to figure out how to incorporate my tensorflow code to run on Redis Cluster.